# Window.location.href is not working with Clipboard JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I am trying to copy the current page URL to the clipboard using the ClipboardJS library. I tried my best and asking the question here.

Here is the Code:

Javascript/Jquery:

```
new Clipboard('.copy', {
    text: function(trigger) {
        return window.location.href;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn btn-default copy">Copy to clipboard</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-target=".modal" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</a>
```

Here is the Code Pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWgZpV

Comment: I changed your codepen to use `return "Some string";` and that didn't work, either. It has nothing to do with `window.location.href`.

Comment: Question: have you only been using codepen for this, or have you tried running it locally too? I have a feeling codepen might be intervening somehow

Comment: @SamHood It also fails as a Stack Snippet.

Comment: This has something to do with the .copy element being inside the modal - if you move it outside there is no problem. My guess is that bootstrap is doing something funky and not loading the DOM inside the modal until it needs to

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
  new Clipboard('.copy', {
    text: function(trigger) {
        return window.location.href;
    }
});
};
```

Seems like bootstrap has some issue with Clipboard library. Thanks to https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/155#issuecomment-217372642